# Regain access to an app created by a FB Page Account

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-page

Several month ago, before FB restricting the ability of a Page Account to create apps, I have created an application and linked to the page.

Now I cannot access anymore to the developers page with this account. I had to create a new app with my personal account, but I can't find a way to remove or unlink the old app from the page.

I cannot create a new page, as a result of nearly one year of activity on the current page, and trying to link the new app to the old page I get an undefined error.

We are in a sort of limbo...

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this situation?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean 'business account', not Page?

If so, and you're still able to log into the business account to manage your ads and pages, you can authorise your app by manually calling the Oauth dialog with the [client-side Oauth flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/client-side-without-js-sdk/), then use the access token (which will be for your business account, the admin of the app), to add your real user account as an additional admin

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#roles

> You can define a role for a user by issuing an HTTP POST request to
>   APP_ID/roles with a user access token for an administrator of the app...

So a call to `https://graph.facebook.com/<APP ID>/roles?user=<USER ID OF REAL ACCOUNT>&role= administrators&access_token=<ACCESS TOKEN>&message=POST` will add another admin

Comment: When I do the POST Request to set a new administrator, I get "true". But with the developer account, I still cant find the app in developers.facebook.com/apps  

https://graph.facebook.com/<APP-ID>/roles?access_token=<APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>  

returns me an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The person you're trying to add is a confirmed developer who can access the apps dashboard normally? it's not automatic, you should need to accept the request to become a developer from the 'new' developer account